# Selecting a default value for list in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to select a default value for my list in my JSP code. I could get the list but when I want a default value if a condition is satified, I could not get the value selected. Below is the code.

I am comparing two values

```
${creditDebitAccountViewModel.expirationMonth}
${expirationMonth}


<select id="expirationMonth" ">
    <c:forEach items="${creditDebitAccountViewModel.listExpirationMonth}" var="expirationMonth">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${creditDebitAccountViewModel.expirationMonth eq expirationMonth}">
           <option  value="expirationMonth" selected>${expirationMonth}</option>
        </c:when>    
        <c:otherwise>
           <option value="expirationMonth">${expirationMonth}</option>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the option actually getting the `selected` attribute if that condition evaluates to true?

Try and make sure that the condition isn't the problem, and if it isn't, try editing your selected attribute.

It's also worth noting your `select` element has a trailing quote after the `id` attribute, which may be making your HTML invalid.

```
<select id="expirationMonth" ">
                             ^
```

Address these problems and your code should be valid, in theory.

Depending on if your page is HTML or XHTML, you may also need to switch

```
<option value="Lorem ipsum" name="placeholder_text" selected="selected">
    Lorem ipsum
</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. The condition is the problem. I am comparing '02'='2'. That's the reason why I am getting error. I have corrected my code to pass the variables in the right format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, if this fixed your issue, please don't forget to mark as accepted answer, and upvote it